# Why does my interface have 2 ip adresses when using NetworkManager

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, dhcp

After installing NetworkManager and establishing a wifi connection my wlan0 Interface got a secondary ip address.

```
~ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:e7:c6:78:2c:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:63:3f:76:6c:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.109/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 1814066sec preferred_lft 1814066sec
    inet 192.168.2.117/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global secondary dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 1814075sec preferred_lft 1587275sec
```

I do not want to have a second IP address assigned to my interface and i want NetworkManager to use the existent connection which was established before installing NetworkManager by using `iwctl`. The existent connection configuration is used but somehow a second ip address is added to my interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that i still had a dhcpcd service enabled. After disabling and restarting my problem was solved.